# How to set dynamic number for margin-left of sibling div element with absolute position in css

Tags: html, css, css-position, margin

As can be seen in the `.half-circle:nth-child` class definition in my CSS below, I am trying to set a dynamic margin-left value for each absolutely positioned `<div>` of the same class, but I cannot get it to work.

```
.header-paymentback-panel{
position: relative; 
float: left;
width: 225px;
height: 150px;
background: #f5f5f5;
border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
border-radius: 5px;
display: inline-block;
}

.half-circle {
position: absolute;
bottom: -2px;
float: left;
width: 45px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #fff;
border-top-left-radius: 60px;
border-top-right-radius: 60px;
border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
border-bottom: 0;
}

.half-circle:nth-child(n) {
 margin-left: /* (20px * item index) */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header-paymentback-panel">

<div class="half-circle"></div>
<div class="half-circle"></div>
<div class="half-circle"></div>

</div>
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a parent to the `.half-circle` elements.

For eg. `.half-circle-container` and give it `position: absolute;`

Then add the `.half-circle` elements with `display: inline-block;`

After that you can set `margin-left` for `.half-circle` as you wish. See code below:

```css
.header-paymentback-panel {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 225px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.half-circle-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
}

.half-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 45px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 60px;
  border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 20px; //Change here
}
```

```html
<div class="header-paymentback-panel">
  <div class="half-circle-container">
    <div class="half-circle"></div>
    <div class="half-circle"></div>
    <div class="half-circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any extra elements, you can use *multiple backgrounds* including a `radial-gradient` for the *circles* and `linear-gradient` for the *borders* - see demo below:

```css
div {
  width: 225px;
  height: 150px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom, #fff 20px, #eaeaea 21px, transparent 23px) bottom left / 33.33% 25px repeat-x, /* circles repeating horizontally */
              linear-gradient(#eaeaea, #eaeaea) left / 2px 100% no-repeat, /* left border */
              linear-gradient(#eaeaea, #eaeaea) right / 2px 100% no-repeat,  /* right border */
              linear-gradient(#eaeaea, #eaeaea) bottom / 100% 2px no-repeat,  /* bottom border */
              linear-gradient(#eaeaea, #eaeaea) top / 100% 2px no-repeat,  /* top border */
             #f5f5f5 /* this color fills other areas */;
  border-radius: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```